# How can I change the highlighting done by IntelliJ when selecting an expression?

Tags: intellij-idea

I started using IntelliJ recently, and have found if I highlight a variable, it does not highlight other occurrences of this variable very bright and so I sometimes miss the other occurrences.

I find the highlighting done on VSC for this purpose is much better. If I highlight a variable `num`, all places where `num` is written on the screen are highlighted nicely. With IntelliJ, its not as good..

Can I change this highlight color?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by going into the Settings.

Choose `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `General` > `Code` > `Identifier under caret`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).